# CTreeCtrl save items added at runtime

Tags: c++, serialization, mfc, treeview

I need to keep CTreeCtrl items dynamically added

Serialize is indeed should do it?
Would only need to convert if yes how variable type

If not how to do it?

Serialize function

```
if (ar.IsStoring())
{
    ar >> m_tree1;
}
else
{
    ar << m_tree1;
}
```

Comment: You need to write this yourself, a CTreeCtrl cannot save it's content automatically.

Comment: Please try to fix the grammar of your question. It is not clear what you mean with "Would only need to convert if yes how variable type"

Comment: I thought if you need to convert from ar to a CTreeCtrl

Comment: The control is the container that shows the data. You need to archive the data that's inside....

Comment: Tag your question as C++. Will highlight the code properly.

Comment: I just couldn't do it.
Maybe you could elaborate a little.
Where do I put the code in a document doesn't display right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serializing a tree isn't as complicated. Here a function with some pseudocode and without error cheching.

The only thing you have to do, is to serialize the nodes data...

This code is not checked against a compiler but should show the way how to achieve this. The code is documented.

```
...
SerializeTree(m_tree.GetRootItem(), ar);
...

void SerializeTree(CTreeCtrl &tree, HTREEITEM hItem, CArchive &ar)
{
  if ar.IsStoring())
  {
    // Count items on this level
    DWORD dwCnt = 0;
    for (HTREEITEM hNext = hItem; hNext; hNext = tree.GetNextItem(hNext,TVGN_NEXT)
      ++dwCnt;
    // output data on this level
    ar << dwCnt;
    for (HTREEITEM hNext = hItem; hNext; hNext = tree.GetNextItem(hNext,TVGN_NEXT)
    {
      // Output data of this node
      OutputDataOfNode(tree,hNext,ar);
      // Stream children of this node
      SerializeTree(tree,tree.GetChildItem(hNext),ar);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // Get number of nodes on this level
    DWORD dwCnt;
    ar >> dwCnt;
    while (dwCnt--)        
    {
      // Insert a new node
      HTREEITEM hNext = tree.InsertItem(_T(""),hItem ? hItem : TVI_ROOT, TVI_LAST);
      // Read data of node into the new node hNext
      ReadDataOfNode(tree,hNext,ar);
      // Now read all children
      SerializeTree(tree,hNext,ar);
    }
  }
}
```